# Show that for $x \in H^∗(X), a \in H^∗(A), d(a \cup i^*(x)) = d(a) \cup x \in H^∗ (X, A)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Could any one help me with this problem?

Let i: $A ,→ X$ be an inclusion of a subset, $i^∗: H^∗ (X) → H^*(A)$
the induced map in cohomology, and $d: H^∗(A) → H^{∗,+1}(X, A)$
the connecting homomorphism for the pair $(X, A)$. Show that
for $x \in H^∗(X), a \in H^∗(A)$,  $d(a \cup i^∗(x)) = d(a) \cup x \in H^∗
(X, A)$

Comment: Please use LateX and properly state your problem

Comment: Figure out what $d$ looks like explicitly. Use explicit cochains representing these classes.